# SQL Query AVG Date Time In same Table Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, average, datediff

I’m trying to make a query that returns the difference of days to get the average of days in a period of time. This is the situation I need to get the max date from the status 2 and the max date from the status 3 from a request and get how much time the user spend on that period of time

So far this is the query I Have right now I get the mas and min and the difference between the days but are not the max of the status 2 and the max of status 3

Query I have so far:

```
SELECT distinct t1.user, t1.Request,
       Min(t1.Time) as MinDate, 
       Max(t1.Time) as MaxDate, 
       DATEDIFF(day, MIN(t1.Time), MAX(t1.Time))
FROM [Hst_Log]  t1
      where t1.Request = 146800
GROUP BY  t1.Request, t1.user
ORDER BY t1.user, max(t1.Time) desc
```

Example table:

```
-------------------------------
user | Request | Status | Time
-------------------------------
User 1 | 2 | 1 | 6/1/15 3:25 PM
User 2 | 1 | 1 | 2/1/15 3:24 PM
User 2 | 3 | 1 | 2/1/15 3:24 PM
User 1 | 4 | 1 | 5/10/15 3:18 PM
User 3 | 3 | 2 | 5/4/15 2:36 PM
User 2 | 2 | 2 | 6/4/15 2:34 PM
User 3 | 2 | 3 | 6/10/15 5:51 PM
User 1 | 1 | 2 | 5/1/15 5:49 PM
User 3 | 4 | 2 | 5/16/15 2:39 PM
User 2 | 4 | 2 | 5/17/15 2:32 PM
User 2 | 3 | 2 | 4/6/15 2:22 PM
User 2 | 3 | 3 | 4/7/15 2:06 PM
-------------------------------
```

I will appreciate all the help

Comment: I normally wouldn't use DISTINCT with GROUP BY. What happens when you take DISTINCT out?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy Since `GROUP BY`, by its very nature, is a `DISTINCT`, it would do nothing either way.

Comment: With your sample data, what would be the output? As far as I can tell there is only one single occurrence where a user has both status 2 and 3 for the same request.

Comment: Thanks,
you  can be use 1 and 2

Comment: The status need to be calculated from status one status to the next 
but 1 and 2 can work

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbf9b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use subqueries since the groups for the min and max times are different. One query will pull the min value where the status is 2. Another will pull the max value where the status is 3.

Something like this:

```
SELECT MinDt.[User], minDt.MinTime, MaxDt.MaxTime, datediff(d,minDt.MinTime, MaxDt.MaxTime) as TimeSpan
FROM

(SELECT t1.[user], t1.Request,
       Min(t1.Time) as MinTime
FROM [Hst_Log]  t1
      where t1.Request = 146800
      and t1.[status] = 2
GROUP BY  t1.Request, t1.[user]) MinDt

INNER JOIN

(SELECT t1.[user], t1.Request,
       Max(t1.Time) as MaxTime      
FROM [Hst_Log]  t1
      where t1.[status] = 3
GROUP BY  t1.Request, t1.[user]) MaxDt

ON MinDt.[User] = MaxDt.[User] and minDt.Request = maxDt.Request
```

Comment: hi, Thank. i try the query and works in some cases but I have thousand of requests and it only show 25 on the result

Comment: Are there thousands of requests for request #146800? That was part of the original query, so I left it the MinDt subquery. Just take it out if you want to expand the result set. Also, if a status doesn't yet have a status of 3, then it won't appear in the result set.

Comment: That was a filter to use the request #146800, I think is my data that is not ok, Let me do a more deep study of my table, But so far the records that show are ok Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the SQL-Server version? Maybe you could use your query as CTE and do a follow-up SELECT where you can use the Min and Max date as date period.

EDIT: Exampel

```
WITH myCTE AS
(
put your query here
)
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```

You can use myCTE for further joins too, pick out the needed date, use sub-select, what ever... AND: have a look on the OVER-link, could be helpfull...

Depending on the version you could also think about using OVER
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: I Have SQL Server 2008

Comment: So you could "wrap" your query as a CTE, I'll edit my answer to give you a hint...

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
(mysql)

```
SELECT t.*,MAX(t.UFecha), x.*,y.*,Min(t.UFecha) as MinDate, 
       Max(t.UFecha) as MaxDate, 
       avg(x.Expr2+y.Expr3),//?????
       DATEDIFF(MIN(t.UFecha), MAX(t.UFecha)) AS Expr1 

FROM `app_upgrade_hst_log` t

left join(select count(*),Request, DATEDIFF(MIN(UFecha), MAX(UFecha)) AS Expr2 FROM `app_upgrade_hst_log` where Status=1 group by Request,Status) x on t.Request= x.Request

left join(select count(*),Request, DATEDIFF(MIN(UFecha), MAX(UFecha)) AS Expr3 FROM `app_upgrade_hst_log` where Status=2) y on t.Request= y.Request

group by t.Request,t.Status
```